# Is "*now*" acting as an interjection rather than a present of time?

Tags: interjections

Is "*now*" an interjection in this sentence:

> "*Now, that's a fast car!*"

I get pretty confused on deciding if "*now*" is an acting as an interjection or present time. I think it is an interjection, but I just want to make sure so I don't look dumb. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It's still considered an adverb in that usage. Here's the relevant definition from *Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged*:

> 3 — used with the sense of present time weakened or lost to introduce
> an important point or indicate a transition from one idea to another
>
> now, this central cord is present in all the vertebrate animals we
> have so far mentioned — W. E. Swinton
>
> now this point of view...seems to me absolutely unhistorical — Edmund
> Wilson

Comment: When is it not an adverb?

Comment: It can be a noun meaning "the present time"; an adjective meaning "of or relating to the present time"; and a conjunction as in "I'm ready to go out now that I have my jacket on." (This is all from the same dictionary entry cited above.)

Comment: If it's an adverb, what does it modify?

Comment: "Is", I suppose.

Comment: Is it because "*that*" comes after?

Comment: Adverbs don't modify *to be*. See the posts by @BillJ at, [Linking verbs and Adverbs](https://www.englishforums.com/English/LinkingVerbsAndAdverbs/nnncc/post.htm)

Comment: To be precise, adverbs  don't modify copulative *to be*

Comment: Is my answer wrong? If so, I'll delete it.